# Matching quiz using action script

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created a matching quiz in flash professional, but when the user answer correctly and want to navigate to the second page , the answers of the matching question appears in the second scene then it disappeared after that in the next scene how can I solve the problem?

```
 var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;
polygon_mc.buttonMode=true;
polygon_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,pickupObject);
polygon_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropObject);
circle_mc.buttonMode=true;
circle_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,pickupObject);
circle_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropObject);
square_mc.buttonMode=true;
square_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,pickupObject);
square_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropObject);
function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void{
event.target.startDrag(true);
event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
objectoriginalX=event.target.x;
objectoriginalY=event.target.y;
}
function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void{
event.target.stopDrag();
var matchingTargetName:String="target"+event.target.name;
var matchingTarget:DisplayObject=getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
if(event.target.dropTarget!=null&&event.target.dropTarget.parent==matchingTarget){
event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,pickupObject);
event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropObject);
event.target.buttonMode=false;
event.target.x=matchingTarget.x;
event.target.y=matchingTarget.y;
}
else{event.target.x=objectoriginalX;
event.target.y=objectoriginalY;
}}
```

and this is print screen
[image: output]

Comment: check your timeline if the answer is not on the second frame too

Comment: they are only in the first frame

Comment: without more info it's hard to help you ;)

Comment: actually i tried to post an image of the output but I need to have 10 reputations to be able to do so and i am still new to use this website... about the frames, the target answers are in one frame and the matched statements are in another layer and one frame also . i do not know why they are still appear in the other scene , i edit the post and put my code.

Comment: where is your function who change the page ? what you do in it ?

Comment: s11_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_65);
function fl_ClickToGoToScene_65(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 23");
}